# Average Difference Between Times on Excel?

Tags: excel

Say I want to find the average difference between a few times on Excel, such as:

- 3:15:45
- 3:25:27
- 3:36:15
- 3:49:01

It seems like the average time difference would be about 11 minutes. How do I calculate exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: Should the last data point be 3:49:01?  Average interval = `(LastTime - FirtsTime)/(CountOfTimes - 1)`

Comment: Can you create new column with difference in minutes for each consecutive entry? And then run average on that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algebraically, the average interval = `(LastTime - FirtsTime)/(CountOfTimes - 1)`

If your data is in ascending order, like your sample, Average interval can be calculated with

```
=(MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A))/(COUNT(A:A)-1)
```

If data is *not* in ascending order (so some intervals are negative) and first time is in `A2` (allows for heading text), use

```
=(INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A))-A2)/(COUNT(A:A)-1)
```

Both these formula allow for any number of data points.  The second requires no gaps (blanks) in the data range

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are in cells A1:A4 -

```
=AVERAGE((A2-A1),(A3-A2),(A4-A3))
```